# Showing that a recursive sequence is convergent using inequality

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

Let ${x_n}$ be a non-negative sequence defined for $n≥0$ so that the following inequality is true for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ : $ x_{n+1}^3<3x_n -2$. Proove that the sequence is convergent and find the limit!

Comment: A well posed question should contain your attempts. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you have $x_{n+1}^3-x_{n}^3<3x_n-2-x_n^3$. Consider the function
$$
f(t)=3t-2-t^3
$$
defined over $(0,\infty)$; the derivative is $f'(t)=3-3t^2$, so the function has an absolute maximum at $t=1$ and $f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM $$x_{n+1}^3-x_n^3=-(x_n^3+2-3x_n)\leq-\left(3\sqrt[3]{x_n^3\cdot1^2}-3x_n\right)=0,$$
which says that $x$  decreases and is bounded ($x_n\geq0$), which gives that $x$ converges.

Let $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow+\infty}x_n=a$.

Thus, $a\geq0$ and $$a^3\leq3a-2$$ or
$$(a+2)(a-1)^2\leq0,$$ which gives $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

- Well this is just a simplistic alternate answer for the first question (both are already answered)

$x_{n+1}^3<3x_n -2$ means $x_n>\frac{x_{n+1}^3+2}{3}$

- if $x_n>1$ then $({3x_n -2})^{1/3}>1$ which means $x_{n+1}>1$ this indicates:

$x_{n}>\frac{x_{n+1}^3+2}{3}>x_{n+1}$

> > *Tl; dw* ,  this was too obvious for me to write:
>
> $\frac{x_{n+1}^3+2}{3}>x_{n+1}$ because $x_{n+1}^3>3x_{n+1}-2$. Since $x_{n+1}^3=(x_{n+1}^3-1+1)^3$ which says :
> $x_{n+1}^3=(x_{n+1}-1)^3+3(x_{n+1}-1)^2+3(x_{n+1}-1)+1>3x_{n+1}-2=3(x_{n+1}-1)+1$

The series is decreasing and positive, so it's convergent.

- If $x_n<1$ then $({3x_n -2})^{1/3}<1$ which means the series is always convergent because it's bounded